# How to pre-load a camera in a PageViewController so that there is no loading animation?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, uipageviewcontroller

My app uses three view controllers in a Page View Controller. The user swipes left to access a camera. When the user navigates to the camera view, there is a clunky default camera loading animation. I would like the camera to be pre-loaded so that the user sees a fully active camera the moment they swipe left and by doing so eliminate the loading animation.

The app is fully in Swift and the camera uses AVFoundation with a custom camera switcher and a label.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shared or global variable for the capture session and initiate/start the capture session when your main VC loads.  Then when your user swipes yo the other VC the session will already be in memory and you just need to set the frame.